# Adding each new value of a String 'temp' value to ArrayList without overwriting previous 'temp'

Tags: java, string, sockets, arraylist, inputstream

My input is coming from a `socket` using `DataInputSteam` and because I can have several different String values all being assigned to same `clientDayOfWeek` string, I cannot figure out how to save all the string values coming in into the same ArrayList without replacing the last value. I'd also like no duplicates if possible.

```
       Socket socket = null;
       DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
       dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                              socket.getInputStream());

       String clientDayOfWeek = dataInputStream.readUTF();
       ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
       String temp = clientDayOfWeek;
       ar.add(temp);
       System.out.print("Items in list: "+ ar);
```

Comment: Can you use the Java 8 streams API?

Comment: What I can't understand is why you assign something to a variable (`clientDayOfWeek`) and then assign it again to another variable (`temp`) and then add it to a collection. Isn't it simple to just store `dataInputStream.readUTF()` in the `ar` `List`?

Comment: declare ur arraylist in a  global location and try adding ?

Comment: Niet, my friend! That's just the beginning of what we all known as _shared state_. Try hard, find a better/great solution, and always (if possible) return an unmodifiable collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Prasaanth, that's what I was doing wrong.

I needed my `ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();` to be global and simplified the rest as follows inside my method.

```
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                        socket.getInputStream());
   ar.add(dataInputStream.readUTF());
   System.out.print("ar: "+ar);
```