# do not add string if string exists arraylist

Tags: java, string, sockets, arraylist, inputstream

My input is coming from a `socket` using `DataInputSteam` and because I can have several different String values all being assigned to same `clientDayOfWeek` string, I cannot figure out how to save all the string values coming in into the same `ArrayList` without replacing the last value. I'd also like no duplicates if possible.

```
       Socket socket = null;
       DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
       dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                              socket.getInputStream());

       String clientDayOfWeek = dataInputStream.readUTF();
       ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
       String temp = clientDayOfWeek;
       ar.add(temp);
       System.out.print("Items in list: "+ ar);
```

Comment: This is the second time you've posted this question. What's wrong with the first one ?

Comment: @ThisaruGuruge why do not you flagged it if it is asked twice?

Comment: @KickButtowski Done already :) But the first question hasn't an answer yet. (It was asked about 20 mins earlier)

Comment: The other question @ThisaruGuruge is referring to seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @MERose No. It still there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29883823/adding-each-new-value-of-a-string-temp-value-to-arraylist-without-overwriting

Comment: Ah, it's written by another user. I was looking on Garretts page only.

Answer (score 6):

You can check if the [`List.contains(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) the `String` already like,

```
List<String> ar = new ArrayList<>();
if (!ar.contains(clientDayOfWeek)) {
    ar.add(clientDayOfWeek);
}
```

Or, just use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) (assuming you want to preserve insertion order) like

```
Set<String> ar = new LinkedHashSet<>();
ar.add(clientDayOfWeek);
```

if you don't need to preserve order I would prefer a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).